# Parameter Count Mismatch exception when calling PropertyInfo.GetValue

Tags: .net, reflection

I'm trying to compare two objects at runtime using reflection to loop through their properties using the following method:

```vb
Private Sub CompareObjects(obj1 As Object, obj2 As Object)

    Dim objType1 As Type = obj1.GetType()

    Dim propertyInfo = objType1.GetProperties

    For Each prop As PropertyInfo In propertyInfo
        If prop.GetValue(obj1).Equals(prop.GetValue(obj2)) Then
            'Log difference here
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Whenever I test this method, I'm getting a Parameter Count Mismatch exception from System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck when it calls prop.GetValue(obj1).

This happens no matter the type of obj1 and obj2, nor the type in prop (in my test case, the first property is a Boolean).

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it so that I can compare the values from the two objects?

**Solution**

I added the following lines just inside the for each loop:

```
Dim paramInfo = prop.GetIndexParameters
If paramInfo.Count > 0 Then Continue For
```

The first property was taking a parameter, which was causing the problem. For now, I'll just skip any property that requires a parameter.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I suspect your type contains an indexer - i.e. a property which takes parameters. You can check for this by calling [`PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters.aspx) and checking if the returned array is empty.

(If that *isn't* the problem, please edit your question to show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the issue.)

Comment: Thanks, you were right, the property was taking in a bool that I wasn't passing in.

Answer (score 6):

This was plenty for me to skip over indexers.

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => !x.GetIndexParameters().Any())
```

Answer (score 1):

for  **`C#`**:

```
PropertyInfo property = .....
ParameterInfo[] ps  = property.GetIndexParameters();
if (ps.Count() > 0)
{
  if(obj.ToString().Contains("+"))
  {
      Debug.Write("object is multi-type");
  }
  else { 
    var propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: For my code to work I had to use 
ParameterInfo[] p = prop.GetIndexParameters();
and ps.Length() instead of ps.Count()

Comment: @BillyJakeO'Connor what do you mean can you post fully?

Comment: @T.Todua your solution works, but scraping an objects to string is a bit nasty.
See my answer.