# asp net parameter count mismatch in recursive function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a little problem with one of my functions. When I commented on the recursive part, I get 4 Items in my DropDownList. However, when I uncomment the recursive part, I get the error "Parameter count mismatch."

I looked at some functions, but I found nothing so far. The function takes the first object which is a formatted JSON data. Then, it should give me the values of every property in my class.

EDIT: I did as in the posted example ([Parameter Count Mismatch exception when calling PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721920/parameter-count-mismatch-exception-when-calling-propertyinfo-getvalue)), but now I get error "System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32" Any ideas? I also edited code:

```
     protected void wystaw_liste(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return;
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            object propValue = new object();
            ParameterInfo[] index = property.GetIndexParameters();
            if (index.Count() == 0)
            {
                propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
            }
            else
            {
                    propValue = property.GetValue(obj, index);
            }
            var elems = propValue as IList;
            if (elems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in elems)
                {
                    wystaw_liste(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (property.PropertyType.Assembly != type.Assembly)
                {
                    if (propValue != null)
                    {
                        parametry_list.Add(propValue.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some properties have an index parameter so `property.GetValue(obj, null)` will throw the 'parameter mismatch' error for those.

See [Parameter Count Mismatch exception when calling PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721920/parameter-count-mismatch-exception-when-calling-propertyinfo-getvalue)

Comment: I did as in the posted example (Parameter Count Mismatch exception when calling PropertyInfo.GetValue), but now I get error "System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32" Any ideas? I also edited code.